# How to access all tags from a DICOM group number?

Tags: python, dicom, pydicom

I would like to extract from a DICOM all the dicom tags with the same group number. For example, I would like to extract all tags belonging to the group `0010`. I tried this, and of course it made an error:

```py
import pydicom
ds=pydicom.dcmread('dicomfile.dcm')

print(ds[0x0008,0x0020]) # print the tag corresponding to group number 0008, and element number 0020

print(ds[0x0010,:]) # ERROR, does not print a list of all tags belonging to group 0008.
```

Is there a pydicom method to do it?

Comment: You can use `print(ds[0x00100000:0x00110000])`.

Comment: Or `print(ds.group_dataset(0x10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mrbean-bremen and @darcymason have said, there's two ways to get a range of elements via their tag values. You can return an arbitrary range of elements using slicing:

```py
import pydicom

ds = pydicom.dcmread("path/to/file")
# Must use the full group + element tag
print(ds[0x00100000:0x00110000])
```

Or if you just need a particular group then you can use [Dataset.group_dataset()](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/reference/generated/pydicom.dataset.Dataset.html#pydicom.dataset.Dataset.group_dataset):

```py
import pydicom

ds = pydicom.dcmread("path/to/file")
# Just need the element group number
print(ds.group_dataset(0x0010))
```

Both methods will return a new `Dataset` instance containing the elements.